# Random output Image in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

As you may have noticed a question I already asked.

But the problems as soon as I apply random. as you have advised me.That's what I get as a result:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EELo_-eh3fA

That is when I use random images begin to jump around the screen.

Here is a code I use:

```
int x = (int) (Math.random() * 290);
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * 290);
        g.drawImage(image, x,y,32,32, null);
```

How can I make sure that images are not jumping.
I need pictures to be displayed randomly on the screen and remained on the spot!

Comment: Add the x,y to a list and draw the whole list.

Comment: where are you calling this code? Sounds like you might be calling it once per refresh and not once per screen generation.

Comment: Please help us by example, took it as a basis:     http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Resizeanimage.htm

Answer (score 1):

Painting may occur for any number of reasons, not just when you want it.

Each time paint is called, it is responsible for rebuilding the entire graphical content.  Basically what is happening, you are assigning a new random position to the image each time it is painted.

Instead, create a reference to something like a `Point` and use it each time paint is called again.

Based on you previous example, you should not be overriding `paint`, but instead should be using `paintComponent` and you MUST call `super.paintComponent` to ensure that the `Graphics` context is updated correctly, this especially important when dealing with `JComponent` as it is transparent

Comment: I will manually draw and define the coordinates.Thanks for the help!